# Prestashop 1.6 - Search indexing keeps starting from 0 products

Tags: php, performance, indexing, migration, prestashop-1.6

we have migrated 190000 products from a remote database to our Prestashop database. We have tried several times to use the indexing option that Prestashop offers through its administrator environment but indexing keeps going to zero and starting from the beginning. We click only the option "Add missing products to the index" and not "Rebuild the entire index". However, the process keeps starting from the beginning. Additionally, we have disabled the automatic indexing process.

So, the question is what can we do in order to finish the search indexing normally?

Extra info that may help:

- We execute a cron job script that updates some products (about 100) every night at 03:00. However, the indexing process gets to zero even when then cron jobs doesn't run.
- During migration process, we exported the source database to CSV files. Then, we imported the CSV data to Prestashop database by using "LOAD DATA INFILE". We did a full export of database, full import and optimized the tables. However, the site is extremely slow except from the pages that are cached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indexing process implies search for every significant word in product title and description, so for 190k products it will be slow. I recommend you that execute Prestashop indexing script by console to avoid timeout. If you can't do this, you can download your DB to a local server, execute the script locally (that way it won't finish early by timeout) and then export index related tables online again. In a regular hosting this I assume that this process will never ends.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facing is because the index for your new products doesn't exist. You have not indexed the products after importing them to PrestaShop.

We suggest you to choose the option 'Rebuild the entire index' once and once it completes you can use the option 'Add missing products to the index' to build index again.

You can find these options from the following menu in your admin panel:

Preferences->Search